# Get the file length in java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to get the file length and the number of blocks, the file is saved in folder in server, so when client send request to get length of file, the client must insert file name and then the length and block number of that file must be shown to client. the issue here is that the length just displays the same number for all files.

**Server**

```
   public static void Filelength() throws Exception {
    int length = dis.readInt();                      // this is the command only
    String filename = makeString(length, dis);


    File file = new File(path + filename);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        dos.writeBoolean(false);
        return;
    }

    dos.writeBoolean(true);
    long byt = file.length();
    long block = file.length()/1024;

    dos.writeLong(byt);
    dos.writeLong(block);


 // dos.close();
   }
}
```

**client Side**

```
public static void Filelength() throws Exception {

     dos.writeInt(2);
     dos.writeChars("go");

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
     String le = sc.nextLine();

     dos.writeInt(le.length());
     dos.writeChars(le);


 if(dis.readBoolean() == false){

 System.out.println("The file not Exist");
 return;
 }

 long byt = dis.readLong();
 long block = dis.readLong();

   System.out.println("number of bytes  : " + byt);
   System.out.println("number of blocks : " + block);

 }

}
```

the result is always appear like this

```
number of bytes  : 4705984196517036032
number of blocks : 4660946338375008256
```

Comment: `writeDouble`/`readLong`?

Comment: Did you check if this might be a communication issue? What happens if you print file size on the server side? Btw: what is `the same number`?

Comment: i am checking that in server side, so the communication is not causing that

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the way that you read and write the data (although I think it's strange that you had to edit to replace the `writeDouble()` -- are you sure you're running the new code?). One thing that does worry me is that you're referencing static variables; it's possible (especially if you're writing server code) that you have a concurrency error.

Comment: To debug, I recommend rewriting your functions: pass `dis` and `dos` as parameters rather than referencing them as static variables. Then create a `main()` that calls those two functions, using a local file that you know exists. If the functions fail to execute properly, you know that it's a problem in the way that you're writing/reading. Otherwise, you know that it's a problem with the way that you're passing the streams to the functions. In either case, update your post with the latest code.

Comment: Oh, and use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` to write the filename. There's no need to write the length and then the characters (and it takes more space on the wire).